# Bit Manipulation and Flags

Tags: c, bitflags

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pteDe.png

A:
When the man page for open says:
    The flags specified are formed by or'ing the following values:

```
       O_RDONLY        open for reading only
       O_WRONLY        open for writing only
       ...
```

it means we should use a logical or between the flags like this: O_RDONLY || O_WRONLY to specify the combination of permissions we want.

B: To indicate different options we use bit flags (rather than characters or integers) in order to save space.

C: Performing operations on bit flags is fast.

D: Bit flags used in system calls are defined in library files.

E: The command chmod uses bit flag constants defined in octal because there are eight possible permission states.

I know bit flags are not defined in library files if it is a good system library. They are usually constants or #defines in the header, not the compiled object, if that is what "library files" refers to. However, I don't understand how they save space, aren't bit flags just integers after all?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, output or assignment, at least hast the courtesy of writing the assignment in your question, so that we don't have to access external resources.

Comment: ORing flags with `||` is obviously wrong

Comment: @Pablo Sorry,fixed.

Comment: No, flags are meant to be bit-wise ORred, not logically as you show. So `O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY`. Such flags are meant to be held as bits in a single variable.

Comment: `|` and `||` are different things. The former is bit-wise OR and the later is the logical OR operator.

Comment: You don't combine O_RDONLY and O_WRONLY flags to obtain read & write permissions. Instead, you use O_RDWR. Only one of these three ( O_RDONLY or O_WRONLY or O_RDWR). Any of these 3 values can be combined with other flags mentioned in the documentation (O_CREAT, O_DIRECT and so on).

Comment: `B` does not hold in this case; the flags in `fopen("foo", "r")` take less space (2 bytes) than these in `open("foo", O_RDONLY)` (very likely an integer with 4 bytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `|` and `||` are different operators.

`|` is the bit-wise OR operator which does an OR on every bit and you get the
result of that.

`||` is the logical OR operator which returns true if the left side is true or
the right side is true, false otherwise.

In case of bit flag, you should use `|`, like `O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY`

> B: To indicate different options we use bit flags (rather than characters or integers) in order to save space.

I think that this phrasing is a bit missleading, to be honest. The nice thing
about bit flags, is that you can pack in a single `int`, mostly 32 bit long, up
to 32 different values that have a ON/OFF semantic. So the function that takes
these kind of options, only has to use a single `int` to get multiple options
from the caller because the single bits represent such a on/off property. If the
bit is 1, then the propery is ON, otherwise OFF.

In constract, when you don't use bit flags, the function would have to take a
separate variable for every options and if you have many options, you would need
a lot of variables in the function declaration. So you can "save space" if you
use bit flags instead.

Consider this:

```
// lot's of other has_property_x cases

int somefunc(int has_property_a, int has_property_b, int has_property_c, ...)
{
    if(has_property_a)
        do_something_based_on_a();
    if(has_property_b)
        do_something_based_on_b();
    ....
}

void foo(void)
{
    somefunc(1, 1, 0, 1, 1);
}
```

This is not very efficient, it's hard to read, it's a pain in the butt to code,
 overall not a good design.

However if you use bit flags, you can save a lot of variables in the functions:

```
// lot's of other HAS_PROPERTY_X cases

#define HAS_PROPERTY_A 1
#define HAS_PROPERTY_B 2
#define HAS_PROPERTY_C 4
...

int somefunc(int flags)
{
    if(flags & HAS_PROPERTY_A)
        do_something_based_on_a();
    if(flags & HAS_PROPERTY_B)
        do_something_based_on_b();
    ...
}

void foo(void)
{
    somefunc(HAS_PROPERTY_A | HAS_PROPERTY_B | HAS_PROPERTY_E);
}
```

is much more compact and readable.

Answer (score -1):

**A Brief Overview of What Bitflags are**

Bit flags are constants that define a set of some kind, usually options of various kinds. Bit flags are typically defined as hexadecimal constants and the intent is to use the bitwise operators with these constants in order to create some subset out of the total set of constants by using the bitwise operators.

The bitwise operators are the operators such as `|` (bitwise Or), `&` (bitwise And), `^` (bitwise Exclusive Or), and `~` (bitwise Not) which perform bit by bit the Boolean logic operation designated by the operator on the two values to generate a new value. The bitwise operators are different from the logical operators such as `||` (logical Or), `&&` (logical And) which are used with expressions that evaluate to a boolean value of true (non-zero) or false (zero).

An example of a typical definition using C Preprocessor `define` directives to create bitwise flags would be:

```
#define  ITM_FLAG_EXAMPLE1  0x00000001L   // an example bitwise flag
#define  ITM_FLAG_EXAMPLE2  0x00000002L   // another example flag
#define  ITM_FLAG_JUMP01    0x00040000L   // another example
#define  ITM_FLAG_JUMP02    0x00080000L   // another example
```

In addition modern C compilers will allow the use of `enum` types as well.

```
typedef enum { ITEM_FLAG_1 = 1, ITEM_FLAG_2 = 2, ITEM_FLAG_3 = 4 } ItemType;

ItemType AnItem = ITEM_FLAG_1;    // defining a variable of the type
ItemType AnItem2 = ITEM_FLAG_1 | ITEM_FLAG_2;  // defining a second variable
```

or

```
enum { ITEM_FLAG_1 = 1, ITEM_FLAG_2 = 2, ITEM_FLAG_3 = 4 } ItemType;

enum ItemType AnItem = ITEM_FLAG_1;    // defining a variable of the type
enum ItemType AnItem2 = ITEM_FLAG_1 | ITEM_FLAG_2;  // defining a second variable
```

And for a few examples of how these can be used:

```
unsigned long ulExample = ITM_FLAG_EXAMPLE2;   // ulExample contains 0x00000002L
unsigned long ulExamplex = ITM_FLAG_EXAMPLE1 | ITM_FLAG_EXAMPLE2;  // ulExamplex contains 0x00000003L
unsigned long ulExampley = ulExamplex & ITM_FLAG_EXAMPLE2;  // ulExampley contains 0x00000002L
```

See this blog posting, [Intro to Truth Tables & Boolean Algebra](https://medium.com/i-math/intro-to-truth-tables-boolean-algebra-73b331dd9b94), which describes the various Boolean Algebra operations and this [Wikipedia topic on Truth Tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

**Some Considerations Using Bitflags**

There can be a few gotchas when using bitflags and a few things to look out for.

- use of a bitflag defined constant that is zero, no bits set, can cause problems
- bitwise operations mixed with logical operations can be an area for defects

In general using a bitflag whose definition is a value of zero rather non-zero can lead to errors. Most programmers expect that a bitflag will have a non-zero value that represents membership in a set of some kind. A bitflag whose definition is zero is a kind of breach of expectations and when used in bitwise operations can lead to unexpected consequences and behavior.

When combining bitwise operations on bitflag variables along with logical operators, parenthesis to enforce specific operator precedence is generally more understandable as it does not require the reader to know the [C operator precedence table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

**On to the Posted Questions**

When a library is provided there is typically one or more include files that accompany the library file in order to provide a number of needed items.

- function prototypes for the functions provided by the library
- variable type declarations and definitions for the types used by the library
- special constants for operands and flags that govern the behavior of the library functions

Bit flags are a time honored way to provide options for a function interface. Bit flags have a couple of nice properties that make them appealing for a C programmer.

- compact representation that is easy to transfer over an interface
- a natural fit for Boolean Algebra operations and set manipulation
- a natural fit with the C bitwise operators to perform those operations

Bit flags save space because the name of the flag may be long and descriptive but compile down to a single unsigned value such as unsigned short or unsigned long or unsigned char.

Another nice property of using bit flags is that when using bitwise operators on constants in an expression, most modern compilers will evaluate the bitwise operation as a part of compiling the expression. So a modern compiler will take multiple bitwise operators in an expression such as `O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY` and do the bitwise Or when compiling the source and replace the expression with the value of the evaluated expression.

In most computer architectures the bitwise operators are performed using registers into which the data is loaded and then the bitwise operation is performed. For a 32 bit architecture, using a 32 bit variable to contain a set of bits fits naturally into CPU registers just as in a 64 bit architecture, using either a 32 or 64 bit variable to contain a set of bits fits naturally into registers. This natural fit allows multiple bitwise operations on the same variables without having to do a fetch from the CPU cache or main memory.

The bitwise operators of C almost always have a CPU machine instruction analogue so that the C bitwise operators have an almost exactly similar CPU operation so the resulting machine code generated by the compiler is quite efficient.

The compact representation of bit flags can be easily seen by using an `unsigned long` to pass 32 different flags or an `unsigned long long` to pass 64 different flags to a function. An array of `unsigned char` can be used to pass many more flags by using an array offset and bit flag method along with a set of C Processor macros or a set of functions to manipulate the array.

**Some Examples of What is Possible**

The bitwise operators are very similar to the logical operators used with sets and representing sets with bit flags works out well. If you have a set that contains operands, some of which should not be used with some of the other flags then using the bitwise operators and masking of bits makes it easy to see if both of the conflicting flags are specified.

```
#define FLAG_1  0x00000001L     // a required flag if FLAG_2 is specified
#define FLAG_2  0x00001000L     // must not be specified with FLAG_3
#define FLAG_3  0x00002000L     // must not be specified with FLAG_2

int func (unsigned long ulFlags)
{
    // check if both FLAG_2 and FLAG_3 are specified. if so error
    // we do a bitwise And to isolate specific bits and then compare that
    // result with the bitwise Or of the bits for equality. this approach
    // makes sure that a check for both bits is turned on.
    if (ulFlags & (FLAG_2 | FLAG_3) == (FLAG_2 | FLAG_3)) return -1;

    // check to see if either FLAG_1 or FLAG_3 is set we can just do a
    // bitwise And against the two flags and if either one or both are set
    // then the result is non-zero.
    if (ulFlags & (FLAG_1 | FLAG_3)) {
        // do stuff if either or both FLAG_1 and/or FLAG_3 are set
    }

    // check that required option FLAG_1 is specified if FLAG_2 is specified.
    // we are using zero is boolean false and non-zero is boolean true in
    // the following. the ! is the logical Not operator so if FLAG_1 is
    // not set in ulFlags then the expression (ulFlags & FLAG_1) evaluates
    // to zero, False, and the Not operator inverts the False to True or
    // if FLAG_1 is set then (ulFlags & FLAG_1) evaluates to non-zero, True,
    // and the Not operator inverts the True to False. Both sides of the
    // logical And, &&, must evaluate True in order to trigger the return.
    if ((ulFlags & FLAG_2) && ! (ulFlags & FLAG_1)) return -2;
    // other stuff
}
```

For example see [Using select() for non-blocking sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715736/using-select-for-non-blocking-sockets) for a brief overview of the standard `socket()` interface of using bit flags and the `select()` function for examples of using a set manipulation abstraction that is similar to what can be done with bit flags. The `socket` functions allow for the setting of various characteristics such as non-blocking through the use of bit flags with the `fcntl()` function and the `select()` function has an associated set of function/macros (`FD_SET()`, `FD_ZERO()`, etc.) that provides an abstraction for indicating which socket handles are to be monitored in the `select()`. I do not mean to imply that `select()` socket sets are bit maps, though in the original UNIX, I believe they were. However the abstract design of `select()` and its associated utilities provides a kind of sets that could be implemented with bit flags.

The evaluation of a variable containing bitwise flags can also be quicker and easier and more efficient and more readable.  For instance in a function being called with some of the defined flags:

```
#define ITEM_FLG_01  0x0001
#define ITEM_FLG_02  0x0002
#define ITEM_FLG_03  0x0101
#define ITEM_FLG_04  0x0108
#define ITEM_FLG_05  0x0200

#define ITEM_FLG_SPL1 (ITEM_FLG_01 | ITEM_FLG_02)
```

there may be a `switch()` statement such as:

```
switch (bitwiseflags & ITEM_FLG_SPL1) {
    case ITEM_FLG_01 | ITEM_FLG_02:
        // do things if both ITEM_FLG_01 and ITEM_FLG_02 are both set
        break;
    case ITEM_FLG_01:
        // do things if ITEM_FLG_01  is set
        break;
    case ITEM_FLG_02:
        // do things if ITEM_FLG_02 is set
        break;
    default:
        // none of the flags we are looking for are set so error
        return -1;
}
```

And you can do some short and simple expressions such as the following using the same defines as above.

```
// test if bitwiseflags has bit ITEM_FLG_5 set and if so then call function
// doFunc().
(bitwiseflags & ITEM_FLG_5) == ITEM_FLG_5 && doFunc();
```

**Addendum: A Technique for Really Large Sets of Bitflags**

See this answer, [Creating bitflag variables with large amounts of flags or how to create large bit-width numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49406316/1466970) for an approach for large sets, larger than can fit in a 32 bit or 64 bit variable, of bitflags.

Comment: I don't think that this `switch` statement works like that, see https://ideone.com/Gg5Kjs or am I missing something?

Comment: @Pablo depends on whether those bit flags are `#define` values or something like `const int O_RDONLY = 0x001;`. If `#define` then during preprocessor step, the text of `O_RDONLY` will be translated into the constant value represented and the compiler will only see constants such as `case 0x0001 | 0x0002:`. But if `const int` or similar is used then I see a compiler error.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. With `const int A = 1`, I get `error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant`. When I do `#define A` or put them in an `enum`, then it compiles. But the `default` case is executed. In your code `case O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY` would be executed if and only if those two bits are set and non other bit is set. If any other bit besides them is set, then the `case` block would not be executed.

Comment: @Pablo I will take your word about the `enum` as I haven't tried that. You are correct about everything else. What is your question?

Comment: `O_RDONLY` can be zero(it **is** on most systems) so, the switch wont compile.

Comment: @wildplasser zero is a perfectly valid value for `case` and will compile just fine. I just pulled an example from the OP's post for the `switch()` just to use as placeholders with no idea as to what the defines would be. This is an example of what is possible not a prescription for what to do.

Comment: @wildplasser does that change sooth your savage breast?

Comment: You fail to see the problem. `0 | n == n`, for every value of n. So, given that O_RDONLY is zero: `O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY==O_WRONLY`, resulting in duplicate cases in your switch.

Comment: @wildplasser I do see the problem with `O_RDONLY` being defined with a value of zero and using it in the previous version of the switch. What you don't get is that that was a generic example which is why I changed to specific defined constants.

Comment: @RichardChambers you've change the code, but the problem I see remains. I don't know if that's what you indented, but in `case GEORGE | BROWNIE:` the comment `// do things if both GEORGE and BROWNIE are both set` should be `// do things if and only if GEORGE and BROWNIE are both set and nothing else`. This `case` won't handle other cases when other bits are set.

Comment: @Pablo ok,  I give up. This is an example of a technique I use in embedded programs and I thought to include it. I did not expect to get hammered and nitpicked. It was done quickly to show an example where sets as implemented with a set of bit masks to represent various states can be useful.

Comment: The problem I have is with the semantics of the comments. For example `case GEORGE`: you say *do things if GEORGE is set*. I know what you mean, but that's not technically correct; this case is executed only if `bitwiseflags == GEORGE`, not if the bit representing `GEORGE` is set. For someone who still has misunderstanding of bit flags, this can be confusing.

Comment: @Pablo do me a favor and review the changes I have made. The original was done hurriedly since the posting was getting downvoted rapidly to -3 and the close votes had already started rolling in. I was unsure if the posting would even survive or if the OP would just delete it from community pressure. And since I thought it a good question I wanted to get something up to start with.

Comment: @wildplasser do me a favor and review the changes I have made. The original was done hurriedly since the posting was getting downvoted rapidly to -3 and the close votes had already started rolling in. I was unsure if the posting would even survive or if the OP would just delete it from community pressure. And since I thought it a good question I wanted to get something up to start with.

Comment: No,I wont.Your original answer was structurally wrong. [as in: a correct anwer to the wong question]